# findall include inside include by use Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i have 3 table vacation and user_mangment and user

what i want findall vacation and then include user_mangment and then include user through user_mangment

here the code what i did ... first relation between models

models :

```
db.user_mangment.belongsTo(db.user, {
  foreignKey: "userId",
  as: "user",
});


db.vacation.belongsTo(db.user_mangment, {
  foreignKey: "userMangmentId",
  as: "user_mangment",
});
```

here code findAll:

```
find_vacation:async(req,res)=>{
  var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
  await   vacation.findAll({
    include: ['user_mangment',{include:['user']}]

  }).then(data => {
    res.send(data)
  })

}
```

and i got error :

```
(node:548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.
```

i don't know maybe i forgot something so please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve it T_T

```
find_vacation:async(req,res)=>{
  var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
  await   vacation.findAll({
    include: [{model:user_mangment,as:'user_mangment',include:['user']}]

  }).then(data => {
    res.send(data)
  })

},
```

better use this code is more details

```
find_vacation:async(req,res)=>{
  var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
  await   vacation.findAll({
    include: [{model:user_mangment,as:'user_mangment',include:[{model:user,as:'user'}]}]

  }).then(data => {
    res.send(data)
  })

},
```